# Removing certain lines from a table

Tags: tables

I have produced this table in LaTeX:

```
\begin{table}[hbt]
                    \begin{center}
                        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
                            \hline & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Examples}\\
                            \cline{2-4}
                            & description & $M$ & \textbf{u}\\
                            \hline translation & through vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
                                1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
                            \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$\\
                            \hline reflection & in line $x=2$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
                            \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
                            \hline rotation & about \textbf{0} through $\pi$ radians & $\begin{pmatrix}
                            -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
                            \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
                            \hline glide reflection & in line $y=x$, then through $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
                            0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
                            \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$\\
                            \hline
                            \end{tabular}
                            \caption{Examples of Euclidean Transformations} \label{tab1}
                    \end{center}
                    \end{table}
```

How do I remove the two external lines from the top left empty corner cell? I want lines only around the other parts.

Also it looks a bit cramped, is there a way I can present it more nicely?

Comment: Welcome. You can modificate directly you table with http://www.tablesgenerator.com/. It very simple and very fast.  Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly modified Mico answer:

- added package `setspace` for vertical space around cells content in last two columns
- `amsmath` changed with `mathtools`, with its `pmatrix*` can be `pmatrix` columns right aligned

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, array, cellspace}% changed package, new package

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}    % add vertical space above cell content
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt} % add vertical space below cell content
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3} % for a slightly more open look
\setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}     % for smaller distances between pmatrix columns
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|*{2}{>{$}Sc<{$}|}} % changed column types for last two columns
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Examples}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & Description &  M  &  \mathbf{u} \\
\hline
Translation & through vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$
            &  \displaystyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
            &  \begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix} \\
\hline
Reflection  & in line $x=2$
            &  \begin{pmatrix*}[r] -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix*}
            &  \begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix} \\
\hline
Rotation    & about $\mathbf{0}$ through $\pi$ radians
            &  \begin{pmatrix*}[r] -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix*}% right align columns in pmatrix
            &  \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix} \\
\hline
Glide reflection & in line $y=x$, then through $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$
            & \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
            & \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Examples of Euclidean Transformations}
    \label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

To improve the overall look of the table, you may also be interesred in `booktabs` package. No need for the vertical rules in this case. As you observe, the table now is less crappy due to the extra vertical space added by the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{*4{l}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Examples}\\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & description & $M$ & \textbf{u}\\
        \midrule translation & through vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \midrule reflection & in line $x=2$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
        \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \midrule rotation & about \textbf{0} through $\pi$ radians & $\begin{pmatrix}
        -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
        \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \midrule glide reflection & in line $y=x$, then through $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Examples of Euclidean Transformations}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better version (by removing the inner `\midrule`s and adding a small vertical height to the row by `\\[8pt]` as proposed by @Mico):

```
\begin{tabular}{*4{l}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Examples}\\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & description & $M$ &  $\mathbf{u}$\\
    \midrule translation & through vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$\\[8pt]
    reflection & in line $x=2$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\[8pt]
    rotation & about \textbf{0} through $\pi$ radians & $\begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\[8pt]
    glide reflection & in line $y=x$, then through $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$ & $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible improvements might be centering “description” (with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{description} and columns 3 and 4.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace the header lines

```
\hline & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Examples}\\
\cline{2-4}
& description & $M$ & \textbf{u}\\
```

with

```
\cline{2-4} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Examples}\\
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & description & $M$ & $\mathbf{u}$\\
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  % for a slightly more open look
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|}
        \cline{2-4}
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Examples}\\
        \cline{2-4}
        \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & Description & $M$ & $\mathbf{u}$\\
        \hline
        Translation & through vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        Reflection  & in line $x=2$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        Rotation    & about $\mathbf{0}$ through $\pi$ radians
                    & $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \hline
        Glide reflection & in line $y=x$, then through $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
                    & $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Examples of Euclidean Transformations}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```